# How can I make Windows 7 stop searching for wireless networks & instead connect to the default one I set

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

On startup, Windows 7 gets busy searching for wireless networks and the progress indicator keeps whirring over the wireless connection icon and only after it calms down after a few seconds/minutes can I do anything else. I have my own wireless internet connection that I always want to connect to and I don't want Win 7 to keep looking for other networks. How can I force Win 7 to do this?

Comment: It probably has to gather the list of visible networks each time; if it didn't it wouldn't be able to see yours to connect to it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the first solution I have:

START, RUN, type: `services.msc` and press OK, here you can manually stop the Wireless Zero Configuration service and and set it to disabled/manual ... or use this tool:

The second solution is to [to download this tool](http://download.elligs.net/wzs123.exe), which will do what it says in the following quote:

> **Wireless Zero Shutdown 1.23**
>
> if you are using a wireless network connection but do not want/need
>   windows to check for available networks every 2 minutes (which may
>   cause unwanted lags, especially when you are into online gaming) then
>   this little tool will help.
>
> this software will stop the wireless zero service once a connection to
>   a router/hotspot is established.
>
> you can start/stop the service manually or set the program to
>   automatic mode, then wireless zero will be restarted automatically
>   when the system is shutting down so the service will be available
>   again at the next start.